# Completely validate URL with or without http or https

Tags: php, regex

I've done some researching on validating URLs in PHP and found that there are many different answers on StackOverflow, some better than others, and some very old and outdated.

I have a field where users can input their website's url. The user should be able to enter the URL in any form, for example:

```
example.com
www.example.com
http://example.com
http://www.example.com
https://example.com
https://www.example.com
```

PHP comes with a [function to validate URLs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php), however, it marks the URL as invalid if it doesn't have `http://`.

How can I validate any sort of URL, with or without `http://` or `https://`, that would ensure the URL is valid?

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you simply append `http://` to it anyway?

Comment: Check out `parse_url()` as a function to explode the URL into components, you could then fix up any thing you need to, and then stitch it all back together for validation. Someone wrote a `unparse_url()` function in the user comments.

Comment: Check if string starts with http, if it does not, append it.

Comment: @ChosenWann That's not validating the entire URL though.

Comment: @Scuzzy: `parse_url()` is a highly unfit choice to start any form of URL validation. It is incredibly hard to find any input that doesn't make it through `parase_url()`. Even strings with several schemata and linebreaks make it through.

Comment: @jprofitt That question is from 2008. It's old, things have changed since then.

Comment: @Bagwell append `http://` to it then validate all of it?

Comment: @Bagwell the internet is old, it still uses TCP/IP.

Comment: Just ran a test prepending 'https://' to the variable.  `https://foobar` passes; `https://foo bar` fails.  In other words, there's a whole lot that's going to pass through as a result—but then again, I guess this would have passed through originally anyway, meaning at the very least it isn't introducing any security risk that isn't already there if you're just relying on `filter_var()` to do the job for you...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use `filter_var()` as you stated, however, by definition a URL must contain a protocol.  Using just `http` will check for `https` as well:

```
$url = strpos($url, 'http') !== 0 ? "http://$url" : $url;
```

Then:

```
if(filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) {
    //valid
} else {
    //not valid
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this will return `true` although `$url = '0812345'`. It will add prefix 'http://' and `filter_var('http://0812345', FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)` will return `true`. Any suggestion solution?

Comment: @fendiSetiawan What makes you think that’s not a valid URL?

Comment: Sure, if I run `parse_url('http://0812345')` it will return '0812345' as `hostname`. Technically, it's true. But, if user visit that url, it will return not found. Since it's not IP address or domain with TLD. I expect some validation that return true only if it's valid IP address or url website with TLD (example.com). Am I get wrong here? Or Am I just not knowing how url are called "valid"?

Comment: There’s valid and then there’s existing or reachable.  There should be a question somewhere that addresses that.  If not then ask one.  You can post the link here as I have some ideas.

Comment: Ah... I see... The "unreachable URL" is what I looking for. Thank you for your help. Sorry if my question make some miss-understanding. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I've also seen this used:

```
$url = "http://example.com";
if (preg_match("/\b(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|www\.)[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]/i", $url)) {
  echo "URL is valid";
}
else {
  echo "URL is invalid";
}
```

Source: http://codekarate.com/blog/validating-url-php

Comment: Because `filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL);` is too long?

Comment: Validating this kind of stuff is [way much complexer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/190405)

Comment: Because `filter_var` isn't available before 5.2, and because it doesn't handle dashes well.

Comment: in 7 it does handle dashes

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom validation rule then add the following method in it :

```
protected function prepareForValidation()
{
        $urlWithHttp = strpos($this->url, 'http') !== 0 ? "http://$this->url" : $this->url;

        $this->merge([
            'url' => $urlWithHttp,
        ]);

}
```

Answer (score -2):

You could also let html validate the url:

```
Website: <input type="url" name="website" required pattern="https?://.+">
```

Comment: Client side validation should never be trusted.

Comment: @Aniket Chowdhury Here's why your answer is out of topic:
1. OP mentions he'd looking for a way to do said validation in PHP
2. Even if we disregard the above, "Let the html validate the url" implies, in the context of the question asked by OP, to let the front end do the validation and accept it at the backend, which is totally not acceptable.

Whether front end validation should or should not be done is not the matter at hand, hence the flag.